# what is command "mvnyjp" in maven for? when to use it?

Tags: maven, maven-3

there are three commands in `maven/bin`:

```
mvn
mvnDebug
mvnyjp
```

I just find nothing about "`mvnyjp`".

How and when to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a script file and therefore readable:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Apache Maven YourKit Profiler Startup Script
#
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#   MAVEN_OPTS      (Optional) Java runtime options used when Maven is executed.
#   MAVEN_SKIP_RC   (Optional) Flag to disable loading of mavenrc files.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ ! -f "$YJPLIB" ]; then
  echo "Error: Unable to autodetect the YJP library location. Please set YJPLIB variable" >&2
  exit 1
fi

env MAVEN_OPTS="-agentpath:$YJPLIB=onexit=snapshot,onexit=memory,tracing,onlylocal $MAVEN_OPTS" "`dirname "$0"`/mvn" "$@"
```

So it seems like it's only of interest, if you are using the [YourKit Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/).

Comment: It appears the license and link has been completely redacted. My copy links to https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Answer (score 1):

Its a shell script intended to be used with Yourkit profiler.

Used to profile maven build process.